# Problem with creating a new picture box!

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, gdi+

First I'm sorry about my bad English. Now I'm having the problem with my C# project ( ms paint). When I open new picture in picture box, the last shape i drew still remain, until I draw the other line on this image. Here is my code:
-Draw line:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        snapshot = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
     }
 if (tempDraw != null)
                {
                    tempDraw = (Bitmap)snapshot.Clone();
                    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempDraw);
                    Pen myPen = new Pen(colorPickerDropDown1.SelectedColor, 5);
                    g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                    myPen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot;
                    g.DrawLine(myPen, pDau, pHientai);
                    myPen.Dispose();
                    e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(tempDraw, 0, 0);
                    g.Dispose();
                }
```

- mouse events:

```
 private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        paint = false;
        snapshot = (Bitmap)tempDraw.Clone();

    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        paint = true;
        saved = false;
        pDau = e.Location;
        tempDraw = (Bitmap)snapshot.Clone();
    }
    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (paint)
        {
            pHientai = e.Location;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            saved = false;
        }
    }
```

- create new picture box:

```
   public void New()
    {

        pictureBox1.Image =null;
        snapshot = null;
        tempDraw = null;
        snapshot= new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
    }
```

-Open the image:

```
  New();
                snapshot = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                tempDraw = (Bitmap)snapshot.Clone();
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                strPath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                this.Text = strPath + " - Paint";
```

can you tell me something wrong? Thnks you so much !

Answer (score 0):

In your very first code sample, am I correct in assuming that the entire `if` statement is actually within the form's `Paint` event? Like this:

```
private void Form_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (tempDraw != null)
    {
        tempDraw = (Bitmap)snapshot.Clone();
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempDraw);
        Pen myPen = new Pen(colorPickerDropDown1.SelectedColor, 5);
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        myPen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot;
        g.DrawLine(myPen, pDau, pHientai);
        myPen.Dispose();
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(tempDraw, 0, 0);
        g.Dispose();
    }
}
```

If so, consider calling `e.Graphics.Clear(this.BackColor)` to clear the form with its own background color. This will effectively erase anything you have drawn. Also, consider the `using` statement when creating drawing objects to protect you if any method throws an exception. I'd rewrite your `if` statement like so:

```
    if (tempDraw != null)
    {
        tempDraw = (Bitmap)snapshot.Clone();

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempDraw))
        using (Pen myPen = new Pen(colorPickerDropDown1.SelectedColor, 5))
        {
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            myPen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot;
            g.DrawLine(myPen, pDau, pHientai);
            e.Graphics.Clear(this.BackColor); // clear any drawing on the form
            e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(tempDraw, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your reply. But this 'if' statement actually in picturebox_paint event. I added a picture box to Form1 too draw on it. Then your code just change my picturebox color same as the form's background. My problem is when i drew something on the picturebox then I open the new image from my computer, the last shape that I drew didn't disappear, until I draw somthing else on picturebox, it's gone.

Comment: `PictureBox` is not meant for drawing on. It is meant to display images, typically from files. Draw directly on your `Form` or on a `Panel`.